# How to replace third repetition of kate with diane in each line

Tags: bash, sed

How to replace **third** repetition of kate with diane in each line only if william appears in sentence.

kate must be implicit - for example "kate's" is not a valid rep

For example:

- kate prince william's wife is the second kate after his mother
  **kate**

will be replaced with:

- kate prince william's wife is the second kate after his mother
  **diana**

but the following one will not:

- kate’s prince william's wife is the second kate after his mother kate

Answer (score 0):

So given this input:

```
kate prince william's wife is the second kate after his mother kate
kate's prince william's wife is the second kate after his mother kate
```

This remove and replace solution works:

*parse.sed*

```
/william/ {
  s/\bkate's\b/XXXXXX/g
  s/\bkate\b/diana/3
  s/XXXXXX/kate's/g
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -Ef parse.sed infile
```

Output:

```
kate prince william's wife is the second kate after his mother diana
kate's prince william's wife is the second kate after his mother kate
```

Answer (score 0):

The most difficult part of this problem is trying to match sentences instead of lines.  If you allow a "sentence" to mean "a string delimited by '.'" (which is a terrible definition, and fails to capture many common instances), you might get away with:

```
perl -0056 -pe 's{\bkate\b}{++$c == 3 ? "Diana" : $&}ige; $c=0' input-file
```

The `-0056` causes `perl` to treat `.` (056 is the octal representation of `.`) as the record separator, so each "sentence" is a single record.  Again, this abuses the definition of "sentence" and misses common cases.  The `i` flag causes the matches to be case insensitive.  Normally, one would use `\b` to match word boundaries, but since you don't want `kate's` to count as a match, you will need to modify this slightly.  You haven't precisely defined what you want to consider a valid match, so perhaps:

```
$ b="(?:(?<=\w)(?=\W|\z|')|(?:(?<=\W)|(?<=\A)|')(?=\w))"
$ perl -0056 -pe 's{'"$b"'kate'"$b"'}{++$c == 3 ? "$1Diana$2" : $&}ige; $c=0' input
```